What is "reqPolicy" referring to in RFC 3161
I'm trying to use Java Bouncy Castle to create TimeStampReq for my TSA according to RFC 3161.
TimeStampReq ::= SEQUENCE  {
   version                      INTEGER  { v1(1) },
   messageImprint               MessageImprint,
     --a hash algorithm OID and the hash value of the data to be
     --time-stamped
   reqPolicy             TSAPolicyId              OPTIONAL,
   nonce                 INTEGER                  OPTIONAL,
   certReq               BOOLEAN                  DEFAULT FALSE,
   extensions            [0] IMPLICIT Extensions  OPTIONAL  }

See the ASN1 structure above.
I cannot understand what can I put in the parameter "reqPolicy". It onlys says "reqPolicy" is an "OBJECT IDENTIFIER". But is there any options to choose from?

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/221967/what-is-a-tsa-policy-oid
